# VueI18n dynamic labels from api call

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-i18n

I want to retrieve the labels from api, they are in 2 languages, and switch them when user clicks to change language. Right now one language is loaded as default, but it is not reactive. How to make it react to user changing the language? I was thinking about somehow calling the function before everything else and storing labels in localStorage

The code: (lang.js file)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import { HTTP } from './../config/http-request.js'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

const locale = 'da'
var langName;

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale, // language identifier
  messages: {}
})
 
function getLang(lang){
    console.log(lang) 
    if(lang == "da"){
        langName = "Danish"
    }else{
        langName = "English"
    }
    HTTP.get("1.0/language/label?language_name="+ langName + "&compact=True")
    .then((response) => {
        var msg = response.data.compact
        i18n.setLocaleMessage(lang, msg)
        i18n.locale = lang
        return lang
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
}


 // This method is called when the manual switch languages, to be loaded when the page is initialized with a default language
// Vue.prototype.$loadLanguageAsync = loadLanguageAsync

getLang(locale)


export default i18n
```

Comment: Refer for translation i18n https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue-vuex-vuelidate-i18n-registration-login-todo